# How to point the range(dataClasses) for 2nd index in data using highcharts?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, data-class

I have plotted a heatmap using highchart , but i wanted to give color range for y axis ie 2nd index in the data array but it takes 3rd index automatically.

Below is the jsfiddle code.

[Links for my code](http://jsfiddle.net/ubjsgtdo/18/)

```
     colorAxis: {
         dataClasses: [{
             from: 0,
             to: 10,
             color: 'rgb(191, 27, 0)'
         },{
             from:10,
             to:30,
             color:'rgb(234, 100, 96)'
         },{
             from:30,
             to:100,
             color:'rgb(242, 201, 109)'
         },{
             from:100,
             color:'rgb(98, 158, 81)'


         }]
     },


        series: [{
        name: 'Sales per employee',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [[0, 0, 10], [0, 1, 19], [0, 2, 8], [0, 3, 24], [0, 4, 67], [1, 0, 92], [1, 1, 58], [1, 2, 78], [1, 3, 117], [1, 4, 48], [2, 0, 35], [2, 1, 15], [2, 2, 123], [2, 3, 64], [2, 4, 52], [3, 0, 72], [3, 1, 132], [3, 2, 114], [3, 3, 19], [3, 4, 16], [4, 0, 38], [4, 1, 5], [4, 2, 8], [4, 3, 117], [4, 4, 115], [5, 0, 88], [5, 1, 32], [5, 2, 12], [5, 3, 6], [5, 4, 120], [6, 0, 13], [6, 1, 44], [6, 2, 88], [6, 3, 98], [6, 4, 96], [7, 0, 31], [7, 1, 1], [7, 2, 82], [7, 3, 32], [7, 4, 30], [8, 0, 85], [8, 1, 97], [8, 2, 123], [8, 3, 64], [8, 4, 84], [9, 0, 47], [9, 1, 99], [9, 2, 31], [9, 3, 48], [9, 4, 91]],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000'
        }
    }]
```

[image]

The actual data is in below format

```
data: [[0, 0, 10], [0, 1, 19]]
```

Now range is plotted on the base of 2nd index ie 10,19 but i want to plot based on 1st index ie 0,1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the default name of the property (of point object) that'll be used to compute the color :

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.heatmap.prototype.colorKey = 'x'; // 'value' by default
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z3b1Lcqg/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts